# How do I wrap text without spaces?

Tags: minted, wrap

I have a very long section title which has no spaces in it. This seems to cause problems with wrapping the title in the table of content and in the header (it doesn't work). I'm also having the same problem with long lines with no spaces using the minted package.

Is there a generic fix for this?

Here is an example (also at https://www.overleaf.com/read/qyvwgrnhpbfm):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\csname PYGdefault@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PYGdefault@bc##1{{\strut ##1}}}
\makeatother

\setminted{
    linenos=true,
    breaklines=true,
    encoding=utf8,
    tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{AVeryLongTitleWithNoSpacesInItCasuesProblemsWhenHavingATableOfContentHowCanIHyphenateOrWrapThis?}

\begin{minted}{javascript}
/ThisIsAVeryLongRegularExpressionOrSomeVeryLongTextWhichDoesNotWrapHowCanIFixThisItShouldWrapOnToTheNextLineIsThatPossible/
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this a real situation or just a curiosity? Add `\hspace{0pt}` in front of the title, like `\section{\hspace{0pt]LONG}`. For `minted`, there's an option to break lines anywhere.

Comment: There is also \allowbreak which can be inserted in specific sites.

Comment: Hi @egreg. This is a real situation. I'm adapting [this](https://superuser.com/questions/601198/how-can-i-automatically-convert-all-source-code-files-in-a-folder-recursively) answer and have some very long file paths (some without spaces) which need wrapping in the table of content. I tried `\hspace{0pt}` and got [this](https://www.overleaf.com/read/xhyxvyzjqdbj) result.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this seems like two questions:

In section headings, you can use `\-` to allow `\LaTeX` to hyphenate there:

```
\section{A\-Very\-Long\-Title\-With\-No\-Spaces\-In\-It\-Casues\-Problems\-When\-Having\-A\-Table\-Of\-Content\-How\-Can\-I\-Hyphenate\-Or\-Wrap\-This?}
```

This also hyphenates in the Table of Contents (not necessarily at the same position).

For the `minted` package you can use the `breakanywhere` option (which egreg mentions in his comment):

```
\begin{minted}[breakanywhere=true]{javascript}
  /ThisIsAVeryLongRegularExpressionOrSomeVeryLongTextWhichDoesNotWrapHowCanIFixThisItShouldWrapOnToTheNextLineIsThatPossible/
\end{minted}
```

Output:
[image: Output with the modifications]